# Unicorn Rails looking for separate file/directory for each command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, unicorn, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy with Ruby 2.2.2, Rails 4, Capistrano 3, Unicorn and Nginx. When I run `cap production deploy` I get an error sating that Unicon can't find or access a directory for the "restart" command, stemming  (I believe) from this line in my deploy.rb:

`execute "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)}/unicorn_init.sh/#{command}"`

**The error:**

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@0.0.0.0: /etc/init.d/unicorn_app/restart exit status: 126
/etc/init.d/unicorn_app/restart stdout: Nothing written
/etc/init.d/unicorn_app/restart stderr: /usr/bin/env: /etc/init.d/unicorn_app/restart: Permission denied
```

**Deploy.rb**

```
set :application, 'app'
set :repo_url, 'https://github.com/user/app.git'
set :deploy_to, '/opt/www/app'
set :user, 'deploy'
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets}


set :ssh_options, {
forward_agent: true,
port: 7822
}

namespace :deploy do

  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc 'Manage Unicorn'
    task command do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 1 do
        execute "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)}/unicorn_init.sh/#{command}"
      end      
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

end

set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.2'
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '/usr/local/rvm/bin' }
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = "#{fetch(:default_env)[:rvm_bin_path]}/rvm ruby-#{fetch(:rvm_ruby_version)} do bundle exec rake"
```

Can anyone help me out here? I'll gladly post any missing info.

**EDIT: unicorn_init.sh: I know 'testapp' is referenced in this file, but `app` is referenced elsewhere in this post. Please know that i'm consistent across all files with the name, I just changed them for the post.**

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description:       Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/opt/www/testapp/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=deploy
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 "
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Do you have a Unicorn file named `unicorn.init.sh` in `/etc/init.d/unicorn_app?  If not, you need to either put it there or change your cap file.

Comment: @steveklein Yes i do. I'm about to post that too. Check the edit. EDIT: Posted

Comment: I've decided to give up for now (having worked on this issue for 2x as long as I've taken to BUILD my application). Most of the information I come across is outdated. I'm taking the easy route and deploying with Heroku. HOWEVER, just like the governator, I WILL BE BACK. I will solve this. I might just have some help. Unless a hero comes along and gives me a blue's clue, I'm abandoning this method for now.